# How to center image on a bootstrap wrapper

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

Here's the part of the image.

```
<!--Need to center the image on my class wrapper -->        
<div class="wrapper" id="mypic" style="background-image:url('desktop/banner.jpg' ); ">

     <div class="container-fluid" >

     <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="caption">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea how could I do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will make much more use of the background rule than the background-image rule. Through the shorthand, you will be able to control its background color, should the image failed to load due no internet connection, and also you can control wether you want the image to repeat or not, scroll or stay fixed, etc.

Try this:

```
.wrapper {      
    background:url('http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/gradient-background.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[See the DEMO](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/bEWMLN)

Comment: why is that if ill use your background:url('http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/gradient-background.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed; I get no error and works fine but, if ill use background:url('desktop/banner.jpg')  center center no-repeat fixed; it wont show the images. Already try to check the path and its correct, my image is in desktop/banner.jpg

Comment: Yeah but, is your solution also in the desktop? The path of your image has to be in relation to the file that you are calling it from. So if your website lives in c/documents/root/mysite/index.html and your image is in the desktop, it is outside of the scope of your site. You need to put it in an image folder in your website folder and path from the index.html in the direction you need to get to the image

Comment: To go forward, you just make the path like image/mypic.jpg...if your index.html is in a filder, you have to get out of the folder first and realign yourself with your image. so you'll path it as ../images/mypic.jpg. The amount of ../ is the many levels in the root you have to get back

Comment: yes it is in relation to the file, desktop is a folder within mysite project/desktop/banner.jpg so it should be background-image: url('desktop/banner.jpg');

Comment: When you run it, check the inspector and see if you have a 404 in the console. Alternatively, right click on the link and chose open image in another tab. Did it come up? No? A path issue definitely. Yes? I'll have to check further in to see what else can be causing this

Comment: No 404 in the console. and it did not come up.

Comment: I sthe website live?

Comment: There's definitely something else going on there.  No errors whatsoever in the console?

Comment: No it isn't live yet. when i try to do inline css for the background image it works. and i inspect element and try console  this is what i've got (Failed to  load resource the http://localhost/desktop/banner.jpg server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))

Comment: That 404 indicates a bad path. The only thing I can think of is a background none rule overwriting your css. Add !important at the end of what I gave you